# Python : crontab error 'Unknown cron range value 0'

Tags: python, cron

I'm new to crontab, and while I'm trying to make python script using crontab in mac OS sierra, I faced error message like this.

```
Unknown cron range value "0"
```

I was following the tutorial.
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-using-python--cms-28231

This is my code.

writeDate.py

```
import datetime

with open('dateInfo.txt', 'a') as outFile:
    outFile.write('\n' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

scheduleCron.py

```
from crontab import CronTab

def main():
    my_cron = CronTab(user='jelly')
    job = my_cron.new(command='python /home/jelly/PycharmProjects/test/writeDate.py')
    job.minute.every(1)

    my_cron.write()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: I tried the above code on mac OS Sierra 10.12.4 and no errors. Is the entire error message you got?

Comment: @manvi77 Yes, nothing shows up except that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still could not figure out the reason why error message keep saying 'unknown cron range 0' but I just found that cron actully worked. 
So I guess the message is kind of warning, and has nothing to do with it.